# I'm Having Problems with NSTimer in Xcode

Tags: nstimer, cgpoint, game-loop

im making a simple game on Xcode and i decided to use a nstimer in my .m
xcode found 3 problems with my code it says Assigning to 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') from in compatable 'int' twice and it says use of undeclared game loop. Any help is great

```
@implementation ViewController 
@synthesize bg, rock, platform1, platform2, platform3, platform4, platform5, platform6, platform7;
@synthesize gameState;
@synthesize rockVelocity, gravity;


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
gameState = kStateRunning;
rockVelocity = CGpointMake (0, 0);
gravity = CGpointMake (0, kGravity);

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0/60 target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)gameLoop {
   if (gameState == kStateRunning)
   {
       [self gameStatePlayNormal];
   }
    else if (gameState == kStateGameOver)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to say 
    CGPointMake (0, 0);
You also need to make sure you declare the gameLoop function in your header file by saying

```
-(void)gameLoop;
```

Your viewDidLoad is also missing a closing bracket. Add one after your NSTimer method.

Comment: how do i say CG*P*ointMake (0, 0);

Comment: There's no need for the stars, I was just trying to emphasize that it should be uppercase

Comment: You need to capitalize the P.

Comment: rockVelocity = CGPointMake (0, 0);
gravity = CGPointMake (0, kGravity);

Comment: thanks i only have one more bug it says use of undeclared identifier 'gameLoop'

Comment: You need a close bracket } at the end of your viewDidLoad method

Comment: that just added more bugs

Comment: You put a } after the NSTimer method?

Comment: what would that look like